# How to highlight all current categories when viewing a single post?

Tags: css, categories

When viewing a single post, the [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories) function already *marks* the current category of this particular post by assigning the `current-cat` CSS class.

If the post is mapped to multiple categories, however, only the first category (hierarchically ordered) is marked.

How can I assign the `current-cat` class to **all** categories of the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to assign the `current-cat` class to all categories of the current post we will *extend* the `wp_list_categories` function by means of a dedicated `Walker`.

Suppose the current setup looks as follows:

```
$args = array(
    'hierarchical' => 0,
    'title_li' => '',
    'show_option_none' => '',
);
wp_list_categories($args);
```

Now we add the walker (which we will set up in the next step), and a new argument `highlight` that will provide an array of the current post's category IDs and that will be handled by our walker. Of course, we also have to populate the very array.

This leads to the following:

```
$highlight = array();
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach ($categories as $category)
    $highlight[] = $category->cat_ID;

$args = array(
    'hierarchical' => 0,
    'title_li' => '',
    'show_option_none' => '',
    'highlight' => $highlight,
    'walker' => new TFCategoryWalker(),
);
wp_list_categories($args);
```

The last step is the walker itself. Basically, we take the default `Walker_Category` class and add what's missing. Therefore we only have to customize the `start_el` function. Directly after the `$class` variable has been instantiated we add the following:

```
if (! $highlight) $highlight = array();
elseif (! is_array($highlight)) $highlight = array($highlight);
if (in_array($category->term_id, $highlight)) $class .= ' current-cat';
```

And that's it.

---

Altogether, this is the new walker class, which we put in our `functions.php` file:

```
class TFCategoryWalker extends Walker_Category {

    function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
            extract($args);
            $cat_name = esc_attr( $category->name );
            $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $cat_name, $category );
            $link = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link($category) ) . '" ';
            if ( $use_desc_for_title == 0 || empty($category->description) )
                    $link .= 'title="' . esc_attr( sprintf(__( 'View all posts filed under %s' ), $cat_name) ) . '"';
            else
                    $link .= 'title="' . esc_attr( strip_tags( apply_filters( 'category_description', $category->description, $category ) ) ) . '"';
            $link .= '>';
            $link .= $cat_name . '</a>';
            if ( !empty($feed_image) || !empty($feed) ) {
                    $link .= ' ';
                    if ( empty($feed_image) )
                            $link .= '(';
                    $link .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_feed_link( $category->term_id, $category->taxonomy, $feed_type ) ) . '"';
                    if ( empty($feed) ) {
                            $alt = ' alt="' . sprintf(__( 'Feed for all posts filed under %s' ), $cat_name ) . '"';
                    } else {
                            $title = ' title="' . $feed . '"';
                            $alt = ' alt="' . $feed . '"';
                            $name = $feed;
                            $link .= $title;
                    }
                    $link .= '>';
                    if ( empty($feed_image) )
                            $link .= $name;
                    else
                            $link .= "<img src='$feed_image'$alt$title" . ' />';
                    $link .= '</a>';
                    if ( empty($feed_image) )
                            $link .= ')';
            }
            if ( !empty($show_count) )
                    $link .= ' (' . intval($category->count) . ')';
            if ( 'list' == $args['style'] ) {
                    $output .= "\t<li";
                    $class = 'cat-item cat-item-' . $category->term_id;

                    // START customization
                    if (! $highlight) $highlight = array();
                    elseif (! is_array($highlight)) $highlight = array($highlight);
                    if (in_array($category->term_id, $highlight)) $class .= ' current-cat';
                    // END customization

                    if ( !empty($current_category) ) {
                            $_current_category = get_term( $current_category, $category->taxonomy );
                            if ( $category->term_id == $current_category )
                                    $class .=  ' current-cat';
                            elseif ( $category->term_id == $_current_category->parent )
                                    $class .=  ' current-cat-parent';
                    }
                    $output .=  ' class="' . $class . '"';
                    $output .= ">$link\n";
            } else {
                    $output .= "\t$link<br />\n";
            }
    } // function start_el

} // class TFCategoryWalker
```

**References:**

- [`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) function Codex page
- [`Walker`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) class Codex page
- [`Walker_Category`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1//wp-includes/category-template.php#L766) class source

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you could alter `$category` if you pass it by reference to a callback for `apply_filters( 'list_cats', $cat_name, $category );`. This would make it able to fake the result of `if ( $category->term_id == $current_category )` for other items as well. But it's just a wild guess. +1 on Q and A.

Comment: @kaiser In fact, I spent some time thinking about using the exact same filter you mentioned. However, I couldn't think of a way that wouldn't affect some other functionality. If I were to alter `$category` (or to be more precise: the category's ID), this would also affect the `cat-item-{term_id}` CSS class. That's why I ended up using a dedicated, extended walker. Apart from the purpose described in my question, one could also feed another set of IDs into the `$highlight` array/parameter, not just the current categories but some important cats that should be highlighted no matter what...